# WFS - GetFeature by Polygon Intersects

Tags: geoserver, wfs, intersection, filter, getfeature

I need to get features by following URL:
[http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeName=datavic:CROWNLAND_PLMGEN&](http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=getFeature&typeName=datavic:CROWNLAND_PLMGEN)

I tried:
    http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeName=datavic:CROWNLAND_PLMGEN&FILTER=
    
    SHAPE
    
    
    -37.2315356,142.8193248 -37.2302536,142.8195475 -37.2300784,142.8179702 -37.2313604,142.8177474 -37.2314496,142.8185509 -37.2315356,142.8193248

Which gives Java error java.lang.NullPointerException. Can someone help with this one?

It works if I use point:

```
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><Intersects><PropertyName>SHAPE</PropertyName><gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4283"><gml:coordinates>-37.2976946,143.7812069</gml:coordinates></gml:Point></Intersects></Filter>
```

Comment: It might be just a typo in the inserted code, but I cannot see a comma between coordinate pairs in `<gml:coordinates>`.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify the &version=x.y parameter, provided like this GeoServer will likely try to parse the filter as a FES 2.0 one, instead of a Filter 1.0 one. Try adding "&version=1.0" in the request.

Also, pretty important to correctly URL encode the filter. This request seems to work fine (added version and URL encoded your filter):

http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=getFeature&typeName=datavic:CROWNLAND_PLMGEN&version=1.0.0&FILTER=%3CFilter%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fowc%22%20xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%22%3E%0A%3CIntersects%3E%0A%3CPropertyName%3ESHAPE%3C%2FPropertyName%3E%0A%3Cgml%3APolygon%20srsDimension%3D%222%22%20srsName%3D%22urn%3Aogc%3Adef%3Acrs%3AEPSG%3A%3A4283%22%3E%3Cgml%3AouterBoundaryIs%3E%0A%3Cgml%3ALinearRing%3E%0A%3Cgml%3Acoordinates%3E-37.2315356%2C142.8193248%20-37.2302536%2C142.8195475%20-37.2300784%2C142.8179702%20-37.2313604%2C142.8177474%20-37.2314496%2C142.8185509%20-37.2315356%2C142.8193248%0A%3C%2Fgml%3Acoordinates%3E%0A%3C%2Fgml%3ALinearRing%3E%0A%3C%2Fgml%3AouterBoundaryIs%3E%0A%3C%2Fgml%3APolygon%3E%0A%3C%2FIntersects%3E%0A%3C%2FFilter%3E

Answer (score 0):

I bumped in to same problem. Then I found https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243490/173422 and realized with `Intersects`-filter, there is a requirement of `ValueReference` (see: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/filter_reference.html).

Example, the GeoServer I'm working with will return geometry in WFS-response field `<geom>` and I need to match that with my filter:

```xml
<fes:Filter
    xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0">
    <fes:Intersects>
        <fes:ValueReference>geom</fes:ValueReference>
        <gml:Polygon
```

Now intersect-operator will have something to match against and will work as expected.