# Filtering layer by Intersects polygon on WFS 2.0.0 in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, post

I am trying to filter a layer by custom polygon that my users can draw in a map.

I can not find a susccesfully way to do it with **WFS 2.0.0** in my geoserver.

What I get from my users is something like:

```
POLYGON((-103.29562334 20.68419619,-103.29525391 20.68419619,-103.29463852 20.68521067,-103.29455649 20.68505401,-103.29332643 20.6855766,-103.29281786 20.68519876,-103.29302852 20.68502881,-103.29266445 20.68458637,-103.29288121 20.68443936,-103.29329203 20.68345206,-103.29360608 20.68350632,-103.29372995 20.68358352,-103.29386379 20.68363493,-103.29394959 20.68370318,-103.2940505 20.68375183,-103.29414635 20.68381257,-103.29430329 20.68387088,-103.29447564 20.68391785,-103.29469879 20.68394823,-103.29499825 20.68397912,-103.29562334 20.68399881,-103.29562334 20.68419619))
```

I have achived an answer from my geoserver, but it is alway empty, with example like this:

```
 <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:Intersects>
            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
            <gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326"><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>-103.29562334,20.68419619 -103.29525391,20.68521067 -103.29463852,20.68505401 -103.29455649,20.6855766 -103.29332643,20.68519876 -103.29281786,20.68502881 -103.29302852,20.68458637 -103.29266445,20.68443936 -103.29288121,20.68345206 -103.29329203,20.68350632 -103.29360608,20.68358352 -103.29372995,20.68363493 -103.29386379,20.68370318 -103.29394959,20.68375183 -103.2940505,20.68381257 -103.29414635,20.68387088 -103.29430329,20.68391785 -103.29447564,20.68394823 -103.29469879,20.68397912 -103.29499825,20.68399881 -103.29562334,20.68419619</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon>
        </ogc:Intersects>
    </ogc:Filter>
```

This is my header file xml post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
        '<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd"> ' +
        '<ows:Identifier>gs:Aggregate</ows:Identifier>' +
        '<wps:DataInputs> ' +
        '<wps:Input> ' +
        '<ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier> ' +
        '<wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST"> ' +
        '<wps:Body> ' +
        '<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="2.0.0" outputFormat="GML1" xmlns:' + workspace + '="' + workspace + '"> ' +
        '<wfs:Query typeName="' + layer + '"> '
```

Comment: WFS since version 1.1.0 requires the official coordinate axis order for each coordinate system. Use latitude-longitude order in your filter. The name of the filter is also "Intersects".

Comment: Have you looked in the logs?

Comment: HI thans, I think the example <ogc:Filter> is with axis order, doesn't it?, logs doesn't tell me something, looks like succesfully call.

Comment: Sorry it was a type, I tried with Intersects function instead intersect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is more of an extended comment than an answer, and I'll update it if more information is forthcoming**

At first I thought this was an axis order issue but it seems not.

I can get a correct response (Colorado) with the following using either `intersects` or the more common `Not Disjoint` queries with this lon/lat ordered polygon:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd         http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeNames="topp:states">
    <wfs:PropertyName>topp:STATE_NAME</wfs:PropertyName>
    <fes:Filter>
      <!--<fes:Not>
        <fes:Disjoint>-->
        <fes:Intersects>
          <fes:ValueReference>the_geom</fes:ValueReference>
          <gml:Polygon  gml:id="polygon.1" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
            <gml:exterior>
              <gml:LinearRing>
                <gml:posList>
                  -107.09346143267561047 39.81837385912805871 -105.24426181667531921 39.7748632799280486 -105.24426181667531921 38.70885408952788254 -107.09346143267561047 38.86114111672790727 -107.09346143267561047 39.81837385912805871
                </gml:posList>
              </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:exterior>
          </gml:Polygon>
          <!--</fes:Disjoint>
        </fes:Not>-->
        </fes:Intersects>
    </fes:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

We may need to see the whole of your request (look in the network tab of your browser) and what you were trying to Query (Mexico?) to see what is going wrong.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, but this is a successful example with WFS 2.0 so I accept this as an answer.

Comment: feel free to edit your question with the info I requested and I'll take another look

Comment: My problem was on WPS defintion, because I was mixing xmlns from different versions to be applied on WFS. Any way this really help me.